# embedded zookeeper for unit/integration test

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, apache-zookeeper

Is there an embedded zookeeper so that we could use it in unit testing? It can be shipped with the test and run out of the box. Maybe we could mock some service and register to the embedded zookeeper

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [Curator](https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki) framework has TestingServer and TestingCluster classes (see https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki/Utilities) that are in a separate maven artifact (curator-test - see the Maven/Artifacts section of https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki).

They're pretty self explanatory, or you can download the curator code base and see how they're used internally in their own test cases.

We've used both successfully within unit tests at $DAY_JOB.

Comment: The Curator testing server also work without the Curator client (directly with the Zookeper client) !

Answer (score 17):

You could use [Apache Curator Utilities](http://curator.apache.org/utilities.html) provided in-process ZooKeeper server `TestingServer` that can be used for testing.
With `maven` you can dependency as follows

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And you can create in process zookeeper server as folows

```
 TestingServer zkServer;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception
  {
    zkServer = new TestingServer(2181, true);
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception
  {
    zkServer.stop();
  }
```

For testing Cluster use can use `TestingCluster`, which creates an internally running ensemble of ZooKeeper servers

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [zookeeper-maven-plugin](https://github.com/revelc/zookeeper-maven-plugin), which is documented [here](http://code.revelc.net/zookeeper-maven-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

The zookeeper project produces a "fat-jar" that it uses itself for system test.

There is a written up [README](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/tree/branch-3.5/src/java/systest), showing how easy it is to launch, but unfortunately it is not being made as an artifact, so cannot be linked to maven.